# Bug in XNA Developer function CalculateEigenVector() from the file "xnacollision.cpp"?

Tags: xna

I am trying to decipher the content of the Microsoft XNA Developer source file "xnacollision.cpp" and I've found a function that calculates one of the three eigenvectors of a homogeneous system of three linear equations. The name of that function is **CalculateEigenVector()** and its content is as follows:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
static inline XMVECTOR CalculateEigenVector( FLOAT m11, FLOAT m12, FLOAT m13,
                                         FLOAT m22, FLOAT m23, FLOAT m33, FLOAT e )
{
FLOAT f1, f2, f3;

FLOAT fTmp[3];
fTmp[0] = ( FLOAT )( m12 * m23 - m13 * ( m22 - e ) );
fTmp[1] = ( FLOAT )( m13 * m12 - m23 * ( m11 - e ) );
fTmp[2] = ( FLOAT )( ( m11 - e ) * ( m22 - e ) - m12 * m12 );

XMVECTOR vTmp = XMLoadFloat3( (XMFLOAT3*)fTmp );

if( XMVector3Equal( vTmp, XMVectorZero() ) ) // planar or linear
{
    // we only have one equation - find a valid one
    if( ( m11 - e != 0.0 ) || ( m12 != 0.0 ) || ( m13 != 0.0 ) )
    {
        f1 = m11 - e; f2 = m12; f3 = m13;
    }
    else if( ( m12 != 0.0 ) || ( m22 - e != 0.0 ) || ( m23 != 0.0 ) )
    {
        f1 = m12; f2 = m22 - e; f3 = m23;
    }
    else if( ( m13 != 0.0 ) || ( m23 != 0.0 ) || ( m33 - e != 0.0 ) )
    {
        f1 = m13; f2 = m23; f3 = m33 - e;
    }
    else
    {
        // error, we'll just make something up - we have NO context
        f1 = 1.0; f2 = 0.0; f3 = 0.0;
    }

    if( f1 == 0.0 )
        vTmp = XMVectorSetX( vTmp, 0.0f );
    else
        vTmp = XMVectorSetX( vTmp, 1.0f );

    if( f2 == 0.0 )
        vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, 0.0f );
    else
        vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, 1.0f );

    if( f3 == 0.0 )
    {
        vTmp = XMVectorSetZ( vTmp, 0.0f );
        // recalculate y to make equation work
        if( m12 != 0.0 )
            vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( -f1 / f2 ) );
    }
    else
    {
        vTmp = XMVectorSetZ( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( ( f2 - f1 ) / f3 ) );
    }
}

if( XMVectorGetX( XMVector3LengthSq( vTmp ) ) > 1e-5f )
{
    return XMVector3Normalize( vTmp );
}
else
{
    // Multiply by a value large enough to make the vector non-zero.
    vTmp *= 1e5f;
    return XMVector3Normalize( vTmp );
}
}
```

In my opinion there are two mistakes:

1) The code snippet:

```
// recalculate y to make equation work
if( m12 != 0.0 )
   vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( -f1 / f2 ) );
```

should be changed with:

```
if( f1 != 0.0f )
   vTmp = XMVectorSetX( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( -f2 / f1 ) );

if( f2 != 0.0f )
   vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( -f1 / f2 ) );
```

2) In the next else block instead:

```
vTmp = XMVectorSetZ( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( ( f2 - f1 ) / f3 ) );
```

we must have:

```
vTmp = XMVectorSetZ( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( ( -f2 - f1 ) / f3 ) );
```

Please tell me if I am wrong or right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point ① is **almost** correct. This is indeed a bug, but your fix is buggy, too. When `f1 != 0` and `f2 == 0` you’re going to set `X = 0` and your eigenvector will be zero. Here is the proper fix, much simpler:

```
// recalculate y to make equation work
if( f2 != 0.0 )
   vTmp = XMVectorSetY( vTmp, ( FLOAT )( -f1 / f2 ) );
```

Your point ② is correct. This is a bug and your fix gives the proper value for `Z`.